# Linked list implementation not forming the links (java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying out a leetcode problem where I need to implement a linked list in java, but the 'links' never get created. The nodes themselves do get created but get lost in memory. I know how to do this in c++ using pointers, but how does this work in java?

The problem:

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
```

Prints:

```
7
0
8
```

Returns:

```
7 (just head node)
```

My code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

        //hold root node to return later, use temp node (l3) to create list
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode l3 = head;

        boolean carryover = false;

        //if lists l1, l2 still have a value, append to l3
        while (l1 != null || l2 != null)
        {
            //always true except on first iteration
            if (l3 == null)
                l3 = new ListNode(0);

            //if l1.val + l2.val >= 10 from last iteration, carry over 1
            if (carryover)
            {
                l3.val += 1;
                carryover = false;
            }

            if (l1 != null)
            {
                l3.val += l1.val;
                l1 = l1.next;
            }

            if (l2 != null)
            {
                l3.val += l2.val;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }

            if (l3.val > 9)
            {
                l3.val -= 10;
                carryover = true;
            }
            System.out.println(l3.val);

            //create next 'link' in list
            l3 = l3.next;
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually every `Node` has a variable, called `next`. The `next` variable is of type `Node`. And if you want to add a new node to your list, the method creates a new `Node` and uses the previous `tail` to `tail.next = myNewNode;` and then update the `tail` like `tail = myNewNode;`. Just google for a `LinkedList` java implementation, there are so many examples.

Comment: you can use class in java similarly as struct in c or c++

Comment: lol, I answered [this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455324/addition-and-reversal-of-a-singly-linked-list/49455848#49455848) on Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l3 = l3.next;` is not doing what you think is doing.

`l3.next` is `null`, so you are assigning `null` to `l3`. That `null` is not a special place in memory that is pointed by `l3.next`, it is just `null`, which means that it is not pointing to anything.

So in the next cycle, when you do `l3 = new ListNode(0);`, you are just creating a disconnected node.

You should first make sure that `next` is pointing to a node, only then you can work with it.

So, try this instead:

```
boolean first = true;

//if lists l1, l2 still have a value, append to l3
while (l1 != null || l2 != null)
{
    // create the next node
    if (!first) {
        // create the next node and attach it to the current node
        l3.next = new ListNode(0);
        // we now work with the next node
        l3 = l3.next;
    } else {
        first = false;
    }

    //if l1.val + l2.val >= 10 from last iteration, carry over 1
    if (carryover)
    {
        l3.val += 1;
        carryover = false;
    }

    if (l1 != null)
    {
        l3.val += l1.val;
        l1 = l1.next;
    }

    if (l2 != null)
    {
        l3.val += l2.val;
        l2 = l2.next;
    }

    if (l3.val > 9)
    {
        l3.val -= 10;
        carryover = true;
    }
    System.out.println(l3.val);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for merging two lists, each lists defined by the first node (head)

```
private Node merge(Node list1, Node list2){
    if (list1.next == null && list2.next == null)
        return new Node(0);
    else if (list1.next == null)
        return list2;
    else if (list2.next == null)
        return list1;
    else {
        Node curr = list1.next;
        while (curr.next != null){
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = list2.next;
        return list1;
    }
}
```